# Unable to download invoice for Azure subscription

Tags: azure, subscription, invoice

I am a subscription administrator.
I can download my subscription invoice, but other users cannot.

Azure portal
Home> Subscription> Subscription Name | Invoice
When you click Download, the following message is displayed on the screen.

"You don’t have access to download invoices or tax receipts for this subscription. Click here to learn how the Account Administrator can grant you access."

↓↓ Access to below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/manage-billing-access#give-others-access-to-view-billing-information

The usage details download button is active,
The invoice is deactivated as "Unauthorized".

The role of the other users you want to download is "Owner".
I also did the following:
Allow users to download invoices

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/manage-billing-access#opt-in

Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: I had the exact same issue a few months ago where all of a sudden I was not able to download the invoices. Please open up a support ticket and the support team should be able to help you out. Billing related support tickets are free so you don't need a paid support plan.

Comment: This is not a programming related question.